# Intermittent error while using EventTriggerBehavior/InvokeCommandAction

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Dеаr Colleagues,

I'm having issues with the following code:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="BeforeTextChanging">
           <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ConfirmEmailCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
     </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I want to emphasize, that the command triggers MOST of the times. The code works. The problem is, it sometimes doesn't. Command isn't called by the evens that otherwise will call it.

The behavior belongs to a Textbox inside a TemplatedControl, which exists inside a ContentDialog. I have similar code in other controls that are part of a ContentDialog and they all have such intermittent problems.

Does anyone have experience with such problems and can you elaborate on a possible fix? What order of control construction and property allocation could cause the Command to not be available for invocation during the event?

Comment: Could you share more detail about your current IME and keyboard type?

Comment: I am working on a Lenovo laptop, but the problem occurs on other machines as well as mine. I have a feeling that this is happening due the asynchronous nature of Layout initialization and management.

Comment: Could you mind share a code sample that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for the help. I don't think that would be possible, because we have a company FlipView control that we use for our project. Sharing that would not be OK. Without it, probably the code will not cause any problems. 

The structure is as follows: event trigger is part of a templated control. That templated control is included in a UserControl for authentication. That UserControl is included in a ContentDialog. I can provide some dummy code, but it wouldn't be working and probably wouldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yep, If you could debug the code please add some print in the head of method to detect if the event has been invoked. if event handler has triggered, we need to check if there is some async process case this issue. Because I can't reproduce your issue, So I just provide some troubleshoot skill.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yeah, I understand and honestly that is all I can hope for. Because I know these commands are not called (I debugged them), all that I can assume is that they don't exist when Binding looks for them. Because we are looking for speedy resolution, I will just break MVVM principle a bit and add commands as DependencyProperties and trigger them with EventHandlers in code-behind.

Comment: Yep, you could listen EventHandlers  in the code-behind. if the event handle could be triggered each time. You could detect the problem in the MVVM binding.